# Collaboration Network plot of institute in R through VOS data

Tags: r

center for sustainable technologies, indian institute of science, bangalore 560 012, india

VOS data gives me that type of nodes but i only want "indian institute of science" as every Node like this so, is it possible to format that data in R for bibliometric analysis.

i am unable to find a way for removing nodes complete address in collaboration network plot.